# Bootstrap overrides scoped component styles

Tags: css, sass, nuxt.js

I have a `nuxt` project, my project `scss` structure is that I have a `main.scss` which is my global `scss` file for variables and font imports and such.

Primary scss I write inside components under the scoped tag.

My global styles and bootstrap seems to work fine, but when I try to
add `scoped styles` to my component, they are overwritten by bootstrap.

For example, This is my navbar.vue component:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>

  nav {
    padding: 3rem;
  }
</style>
```

The components bootstrap elements work fine but my added `padding` is overwritten.

Here is my `nuxt.config`:

```
  css: [
    // '@/assets/scss//bootstrap.css',
    '@/assets/scss/main.scss',
  ],
     modules: [
        ...
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt'
      ],

      bootstrapVue: {
        bootstrapCSS: false,
        bootstrapVueCSS: false
      },

  styleResources: {
    scss: ['./assets/scss/*.scss']
  },
```

Here is my `main.scss`:

```
@import "variables";
@import "fonts";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

If i remove my bootstrap.scss import I ofcourse lose my bootstrap styling, but the styling I've added in my scoped component works.

Answer (score 1):

As I know the attribute `scoped` is actual not supported well by browsers. The status of the element is more experimental as I remember. So if you use scoped styles they may be not prioritised over the other stylesheets.

Maybe you may have a look to `canIUse.com`:
https://caniuse.com/?search=scoped